# str_replace by adding a slash after a word php

Tags: php, preg-replace

Basically I have this url http://xxxxxxx.xxx/example.com/category-1sub-category-11/products.html and I have this string `sub-category-11` and I want to add a slash before the string as such : http://xxxxx.xxx/example.com/category-1/sub-category-11/products.html.

```
$url = 'http://localhost/example.com/category-1sub-category-11/products.html';
$string = 'sub-category-11';
$new_url = preg_replace('/\b'.$string.'\b/', '/'.$string, $url);
```

Any help with this? Much appreciatd.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to not build it like that in first place rather than changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this...

```
$new_url = str_replace($string, '/' . $string, $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace` for this purpose. Just replace category-1 with category-1/

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/example.com/category-1sub-category-11/products.html';
$string = 'category-1';
$new_url = str_replace($string, $string.'/', $url);
```

or sub-category-11 with /sub-category-11

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/example.com/category-1sub-category-11/products.html';
$string = 'sub-category-11';
$new_url = str_replace($string, '/' . $string, $url);
```

Hope this helps you